# How Do I Do A Repair Install For Windows 10 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-10

I am having problems getting to the Windows 10 login screen after booting (I'm left with a black screen and a mouse pointer).

I'm considering doing a repair install and making Windows keep my personal files.

However, after burning a USB stick with the Media Creation Tool it seems as though the iso is only for Windows Home and Pro.

If I continue with the repair install using this ISO am I going to be left with an instance of Windows that can't be activated (since my licence is for Enterprise and not Home or Pro)?

The reset this PC option fails.

Is there any other option to re-install the enterprise edition (assuming that I can't get in to the office)?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise ISOs can only be downloaded from the [volume center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) website (same website you initial downloaded the ISO for the installation your using).  However, the only way to do a in-place repair, is to start the install within Windows.  Which based on your description currently isn’t possible.  You also have to use the ISO for the version of Windows you have installed.  Media Creation Tool can’t be used for Enterprise ISOs

Comment: So, this is your company's laptop? If that is the case you must contact your company IT staff for this.